# Freebsd Linux target in Electron. Is it possible to use the generated file with ".freebsd" extension in the Freebsd Os?

Tags: electron, freebsd, electron-builder

I'm working on generating a Freebsd application with Electron builder. If I specify "freebsd" target in the electron-builder.json

```
"linux": {
"icon": "dist/assets/icons",
"target": [
  "freebsd"
 ]
}
```

After the build, I receive a file with the "*.freebsd" extension, but Freebsd considers this file as "*.xz" archive. If I decompress this archive and try to execute the main application file I receive:

> execvp: Exec format error

Is there a way to work with "*.freebsd" extension? If no for what this "freebsd" target in Electon builder at all?

Comment: Try using `file` command to determine the file type.

Comment: @arrowd meta-0.0.1.freebsd: XZ compressed data

Comment: Don't know if it matters but FreeBSD is not Linux.

Comment: @Rob, yeah, I do know. In the Electron builder for some reason, Freebsd target option is in the Linux section.

Comment: @OlegKornii So, there is an XZ archive inside XZ archive? Then unpack it too.